# CSS: Hide empty column on SharePoint List

Tags: list-view, css, column, cewp, header

How do you delete or make hidden this additional column that sticks out from the header row?

Can this be done using the HTML or Content editor?

See attachments below.

[image]
[image]

Content Editor:

```
<style type="text/css">
table.ms-listviewtable tr:nth-child(2n+1) td, table.ms-listviewtable tr th {
        background-color: #efefef;
        /*border-bottom-color: #d5d5d5 !important;*/
        border-top-color: #d5d5d5 !important;
        border-width: 1px !important;
        font-family: "Open Sans",Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif !important;
        border-collapse: collapse !important;
    }

    table.ms-listviewtable tr:nth-child(2n) td, table.ms-listviewtable tr th {
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        /*border-bottom-color: #d5d5d5 !important;*/
        border-top-color: #d5d5d5 !important;
        border-width: 1px !important;
        font-family: "Open Sans",Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif !important;
        border-collapse: collapse !important;
    }
   .ms-core-pageTitle, .ms-core-pageTitle a 
    {font-weight: Bold}
.ms-vb2, .ms-vb, .ms-vb a, .ms-vb-user A
{font-size: 10pt; color: black; font-family: Times New Roman}  
.ms-vh-div, .ms-vh-div A 
{font-size: 11pt; color: black; font-weight: Bold; font-family: Times New Roman}
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2-nograd,
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh-icon, /* Input box and attachment icon */
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh, /* Text */
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2,
    tr.ms-viewheadertr >th.ms-vh2-nofilter,
    tr.ms-viewheadertr >th.ms-vh-div/* Text */ {
        background: #D3D3D3;
    }
table.ms-listviewtable tr:nth-child(2n) td, table.ms-listviewtable tr th 
{background-color: #D3D3D3;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this to successfully hide the recent changes element on the quick launch bar, maybe this will work for your issue. Replace ".s4-recentchanges" with your particular element and place it in a CEWP.

```
<style type="text/css">
.s4-recentchanges {
  display:none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are looking for hiding the extra TH tag from the table. If I am right you can just add the following CSS to the content editor.

```
.ms-listviewtable tr th:last-child {
   display: none;
}
```

You can simply add to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 views that don't have grouping, that's the 'Add Column' span that's used for quick view. You'll probably have to do it in javascript/JQuery
The structure is (as you can see in your image)

```
<th title="" class="ms-vh-icon" scope="col">
    <span class="ms-addcolumn-span"></span>
</th>
```

JQuery could be something like this, with your usual structure of JQuery references and your structure of code.

```
$('span.ms-addcolumn-span').parent().hide();
```

A full example to put on a view in a snippet or CEWP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/JQuery/JQueryMin-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('span.ms-addcolumn-span').parent().hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: or without the 90KB jQuery library: ``document.querySelector('span.ms-addcolumn-span').parentNode.style.display='none';``